# touch events in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touch

I'm new to iPhone development. I have so many `UIImageView`s added as subview at runtime to the `self.view`.

My current architecture is:

1. Inside `UIView` there is a `UIScrollView` and inside `UIScrollView` there is another `UIView` which is attached to a `UIView` sub class named `SeatingPlan`.
2. `SeatingPlan` only draws the grid on the screen.
3. The `UIImageView`s are drawn on the screen the by `UIViewController` sub class named `SeatingPlanViewContoller`. The `UIImageView`s are added as the subviews.

The `UIImageView`s are saved in an `NSMutableArray`.

The .h file:

```
@interface SeatingPlanViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView * scrollView;
    SeatingPlan * planView;
    CGPoint  origin;
    NSMutableArray * arrayOfImages;
}
```

The .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Seating Planner"];

    UIBarButtonItem *mySave = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(Save)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = mySave;
    [mySave release];

    segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
    segmentController.momentary = YES; 

    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280.0,960.0);

    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;    
    [planView addSubview:scrollView];
    [self.view addSubview:planView];
}
```

I want to move the `UIImageView`s on the screen. I would prefer some sample code.

Where should I put my touch handling code? In the view controller subclass or in the `UIView` subclass?

Comment: Did you tackle your problem? If so, please post your solution here as it might help others. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to move the image views?  Do you mean in another way besides having the scroll view pan around?